# Class template specialization within template class

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, sfinae

Re-factoring legacy code I want to merge separate template classes/structs that are related to each other (to avoid namespace pollution).

`Nested` (below) is a helper class for `MyStruct`, which i want to move **into** `MyStruct`.

But I cannot make this work:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

struct YES {} ;
struct NO {};

template <typename TYPE>
struct MyStruct
{

    template <typename TYPE_AGAIN = TYPE, typename SELECTOR = NO>
    struct Nested
    {
        static void Print(void)
        {
            std::cout << "MyStruct::Nested<bool = false>::Print()" << std::endl;
        }
    };


    template <>
    struct Nested<TYPE, typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<TYPE>::value, YES>::type>
    {
        static void Print(void)
        {
           std::cout << "MyStruct::Nested<bool = true>::Print()" << std::endl;
        }
    }; 

};
```

the compiler complains:

```
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++11 -MMD -MP -MF"main.d" -MT"main.d" -o "main.o" "../main.cpp"
In file included from ../main.cpp:8:0:
../MyStruct.h:31:12: error: explicit specialization in non-namespace scope ‘struct MyStruct<TYPE>’
  template <>
            ^
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

Actually it also bothers me to have to include

> ```
> <typename TYPE_AGAIN = TYPE>
> ```

But without, there are even more complains:

```
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++11 -MMD -MP -MF"main.d" -MT"main.d" -o "main.o" "../main.cpp"
In file included from ../main.cpp:8:0:
../MyStruct.h:31:12: error: explicit specialization in non-namespace scope ‘struct MyStruct<TYPE>’
  template <>
            ^
../MyStruct.h:32:9: error: template parameters not used in partial specialization:
  struct Nested<typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<TYPE>::value, YES>::type>
     ^
../MyStruct.h:32:9: error:         ‘TYPE’
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't specialize templates in non-namespace scope, like a `struct` in your case.

You would have to put the specializations outside of the struct definition:

```
template<typename TYPE> template<>
struct MyStruct<TYPE>::Nested<...> {};
```

But now you have another problem, *if you want to specialize a template inside of a template class, you'll have to specialize it for every template class*. You can't just specialize one member function, you have to specialize the whole class.

So, you need to do this:

```
template<> template<>
struct MyStruct<int>::Nested<...> {};
```

Also, you really don't need SFINAE for this:

```
template<typename SELECTOR>
struct Nested; // Default invalid SELECTOR

template<>
struct Nested<YES> { /*...*/ };

template<>
struct Nested<NO> { /*...*/ };
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! - this template<> template<> syntax is new to me.

Comment: Well, seems i was too fast taking this as a solution for my problem.

Comment: I am still running in circles. Having to fully specialize the outer class MyClass is bad. I want to make use of the inner class Nested being specialized driven by the template parameter <TYPE> of MyClass. Seems, that is not possible? Or is it just "bad design" - we have to use external policy classes for this and cannot embed it into the MyClass?

Comment: @FrankBergemann Yeah,. this isn't possible unfortunately. I don't know any other designs choices you could use though.

Answer (score 2):

It seems there are 2 reasons why you can not compile your code:

- a *full specialization* of a *inner template class* can not be declared inside the class. The best solution is to add a dumb defaulted template parameter, and then *declare a partial specialization* of the inner template class.
- A template specialization can not *directly* be disabled with `std::enable_if`. But we can use the `void_t` trick to do it. `void_t` is a c++17 feature, so with earlier c++ standard we need to provides its definition. I took the `void_t` definition from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/void_t.

So you could rewrite your code as follow:

```
 #include <type_traits>
 #include <iostream>
 #include <type_traits>

 //Crédit: cpp-reference.com
 template<typename... Ts> struct make_void { typedef void type;};
 template<typename... Ts> using void_t = typename make_void<Ts...>::type;

 template <typename TYPE>
 struct MyStruct
 {
     //The third parameter is an unused parameter 
     template <typename TYPE_AGAIN = TYPE, typename SELECTOR = void
               , typename = void>
     struct Nested
     {
         static void Print(void)
         {
             std::cout << "MyStruct::Nested<bool = false>::Print()" << std::endl;
         }
     };

     //We declare a partial specialization, T go to the third parameter. We use the void_t trick here.
     template <class T>
     struct Nested<TYPE,
                  void_t<typename std::enable_if<
                                      std::is_integral<TYPE>::value>::type>
                        ,T>
     {
         static void Print(void)
         {
            std::cout << "MyStruct::Nested<bool = true>::Print()" << std::endl;
         }
     }; 

 };

 int main(){
    MyStruct<int>::Nested<>::Print();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
 }
```

Comment: This.is.AWESOME. It's so clever to declare partial specialization.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to make it work:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template <typename TYPE>
struct MyStruct
{
  template <typename SEL_TYPE = TYPE>
  static typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<SEL_TYPE>::value && std::is_same<TYPE, SEL_TYPE>::value, void>::type
  Print(void)
  {
    std::cout << "MyStruct::Nested<is_integral::Print()" << std::endl;
  }

  template <typename SEL_TYPE = TYPE>
  static typename std::enable_if<!std::is_integral<SEL_TYPE>::value && std::is_same<TYPE, SEL_TYPE>::value, void>::type
  Print(void)
  {
    std::cout << "MyStruct::Nested<not is_integral>::Print()" << std::endl;
  }

};
```

The struct Nested was actually obsolet - this was just a leftover from being modelled separately before.

It was the Print() function that i wanted to incorporate.

However, std::is_same<> is required here to force < SEL_TYPE = TYPE >.
Otherwise someone might invoke

```
MyStruct<std::string>::Print<int>();
```

Comment: Is there a way to turn this working option into one with less syntactic sugar - making use of SEL_TYPE = TYPE?